# Password protect "home" button on iPad

Tags: ipad

I'd like to password protect my ipad's home button... basically we have the ipad set up as a kiosk in our store and would like to prevent people from closing the browser by clicking the home button. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I think this should be asked in http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is to physically hide the button from users, since you can't currently disable/password protect the home button.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ipad1 you can jailbreak it. Then install incarcerapp. When your in the application you want running you start it to disable the home button. It can be started in different ways like toggle the mute button off then on fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you're up for jailbreaking, incarcer app seems like a great solution.

There's also a new hardware solution, adhesive-backed aluminum home button covers. They allow home button activation through a pinhole, using a paperclip (similar to many popular metal enclosures). [BubCap Pro](http://bubcap.com/bubcap-pro.html) http://bubcap.com/bubcap-pro.html